# Can't ping across router with two interfaces

Tags: router, lan, ping, networking, vpc

This is the topology I'm working with.

In the router, `e0` is `ether1` and `e1` is `ether2`.

`LAN_A` has a maximum of `96` clients.

`LAN_B` has a maximum of `48` clients.

[image]

VPC_LAN_A:

`ip 192.168.10.1/25 192.168.10.10`

VPC_LAN_B:

`ip 192.168.10.2/26 192.168.10.20`

Router_1_Mikrotik:

`add address=192.168.10.10/24 interface=ether1`

`add address=192.168.10.20/24 interface=ether2`

The goal is to ping from `LAN_A` to `LAN_B`, but it seems like it's not possible with this configuration and I can't figure out why.

Comment: as per your diagram  you have been connected `eth 0`and  `eth 1`.  But your ip configurations on `ether1` and `ether2`

Comment: In the router, e0 is ether1 and e1 is ether2.

Comment: next thing you don't have configured routing or you don't have posted

Comment: For a router to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: @G.Cunha  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/conduct#personal-attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VPC_LAN_A: ip 192.168.10.1/25 192.168.10.10
Router_1_Mikrotik: add address=192.168.10.10/24 interface=ether1

VPC_LAN_B: ip 192.168.10.2/26 192.168.10.20
Router_1_Mikrotik: add address=192.168.10.20/24 interface=ether2
```

You've got overlapping subnets. The VPCs aren't in the same subnet as the router ports facing them. Even if both router ports are switched/bridged, that can't work. Even then, the subnets are partially overlapping - they're not identical.

You need to use a separate IP subnet off each router port. Each subnet needs to be the same on the router interface and the VPC. Subnets must not overlap.